# How to Open a new modal WITHOUT closing the current modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to open a modal that will not close the current modal?

I have this code that i get in this page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bs-example {
      <!--from ww w .j a v a 2s .co m-->margin: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch
          Demo Modal</a>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>ID</label> <input type="text"><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Take Photo">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What i want to happen is when i click the 'Take Photo' button inside the modal it will open a new modal that will not close the other modal or the current modal Thank You Very Much..

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this ?

https://codepen.io/Sachin4dotnet/pen/KxJQMX

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" action='#' method="post">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="signin">Sign In Now</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sign In Error</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//trigger next modal
$("#signin").on( "click", function() {
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');  
});
```

There is another one option which better one but have more JS/CSS -
https://codepen.io/maouida/pen/NPGaaN

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap Version 5.2.3, it is stated that **Please note multiple modals cannot be open at the same time**. But if you are sure that you need to have two open modals at the same time, You can refer to **[this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446029/how-can-i-open-multiple-bootstrap-5-modals-without-closing-the-old-ones)**.